# Not able to get value from associate model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid

Relevant items being used: Rails 3.2, Mongoid and devise.

I have the following two models:

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    has_one :profile, autosave: true, dependent: :delete
    field :account_level
end


class Profile
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    belongs_to :user
    field :display_position
end
```

My app is set up so on successful registration of an account (User) the person is automatically redirected to create a new Profile. `account_level` is defined automatically based on some other logic in the app.

I would like the value of `display_position` to be automatically populated based on the `account_level` of the User model.

I've tried various ways of getting this to work but I can seem to figure it out.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Use a `before_save` or `before_create` filter on your model.

Comment: I've done that but the association is created as yet. When I try to run `self.position_order = profile.user.account_level` it throws an error because the user association hasn't been created with the profile as yet.

Comment: Then try and `after_save` or `after_create` filter.

Comment: Tried...neither works. Which doesn't make sense to me. That's why I'm thinking I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As the people say in the comments, use callback for this:

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    has_one :profile, autosave: true, dependent: :delete
    field :account_level
end


class Profile
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    belongs_to :user
    field :display_position

    before_create do
      self.display_position = self.user.account_level
    end
end
```

Then in the console you can check it:

```
user = User.create( account_level: 'hello')
profile = Profile.create( user: user )
profile.display_position
 => "hello"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Drinor. This is very similar to what I've tried to do but I'm still coming up with the same error `undefined method `account_level' for nil:NilClass`. It doesn't seem to have created and stored the profile in the DB (which means it's not associated with a user) which is why it's throwing the error. If I use the `after_save` filter a profile is created in the DB but not associated with the user as yet - thus still returning the same error. Any ideas as to what's happening?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is maybe it has something to do with the way mongoid creates/saves models that `belong_to` another model. Once the profile is saved (the users actually hits save profile on the form) I can then call `self.user.account_level` on it.

Comment: Sorry but I would need see the complete code for help you. Where and how are you create the User and Profile ?